# CASE WHEN logic

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, case-when

I am trying to compare data in two separate tables and return a "Mismatch" code if the data doesn't match in the two tables.  My problem is that in the `SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader` table the `SalesPersonNo` is 0 and the matching response in the `DailySales_BB.dbo.Exceptions` table is `DestinationTerritory` which is 50.  My logic is to say that if `SalesPersonNo` equals 0 then return 50 to match the `DestinationTerritory`.  When I use this logic (see code below) the report generates all NULLS.

It seems like simple logic, but it has stumped me??  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
SELECT  
    SOH.SalesOrderNo ,
    'Territory Mismatch - Exception' AS [ReasonForError]
FROM    
    ASHEVMSAGE100.MAS_PHE.dbo.SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader SOH,
    ASHEVMSQL.DailySales_BB.dbo.Exceptions EX
WHERE 
    (CASE 
        WHEN CAST(SOH.SalespersonNo AS INT) = '0'
           THEN '50' 
           ELSE CAST(SOH.SalespersonNo AS INT) 
     END) <>
    CASE WHEN (...multiple cases...)
           THEN EX.DestinationTerritory
```

Comment: Can you please be more clear about this problem?

Comment: In your very first `WHEN` clause - since you're *already* and *explicitly* casting your value to an `INT`, you **definitely** don't need any *single quotes* on the value you compare to! `WHEN CAST(SOH.SalespersonNo AS INT) = 0` otherwise you just incur two more unnecessary implicit int-to-string conversions...... Also, since the second value you return again is an `INT`, you should **also** remove the single quotes from your `'50'` value! It's not a string, after all - but a **number**

Comment: @marc_s...thank you for the information! I am a self-taught SQL novice so I'm new to the SQL lingo.  I know how it works, but using tech terms to describe it are still fairly new to me.

Comment: @RaffaelBecharaRameh...let me try to make it simpler in hopes that you might be able to help.  I have table A and record D in that table has a value of 0. In table B record D has a value of 50.  Value 0 in Table A is the equivalent of value 50 in Table B.  However, literally 0 does not equal 50. I have to use a case when statement to turn value 50 in Table B into 0 so that it doesn't show as a "mismatch" or vice versa...I'm open to suggestions.  I have other cases in Table B to check for, but when I add this specific case, my whole report breaks due to NULLS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your case logic.   Try this:

```
SELECT  
    SOH.SalesOrderNo ,
    'Territory Mismatch - Exception' AS [ReasonForError]
FROM    
    ASHEVMSAGE100.MAS_PHE.dbo.SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader SOH,
    ASHEVMSQL.DailySales_BB.dbo.Exceptions EX
WHERE 
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(SOH.SalespersonNo AS INT) = 0
           THEN 50 
           ELSE CAST(SOH.SalespersonNo AS INT) 
     END <>
    CASE WHEN (...multiple cases...)  --make sure all cases result in an INT
           THEN CAST(EX.DestinationTerritory AS INT)
```